# Delete files less than a specific size

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to delete all files that are less than a specific size in a directory. Does anyone know if there is a Windows command that will do this? something like `del *.* where size<3kb`

I am currently doing this:

```
for /F %%A in ("*.pdf") do If %%~zA LSS 20103409 del %%~fA
```

and the ouput I get is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Desktop\test>If 6440450 LSS 20103409 del C:\Do
cuments and Settings\agordon\Desktop\test\US Tox 01-06-11.pdf
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

...even though that PDF file is small enough to be deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

This is actually working:

```
FOR %%F IN (*.pdf) DO (
IF %%~zF LSS 20103409  DEL %%F
)
```

However it is not recognizing the file names because they have spaces! How do I convert the Windows name to a "DOS" name in that script? For example, the Windows name is `file name.pdf` I would probably need to convert to "DOS" and it would look like this `file_name.pdf` or something like that.

Comment: looks like i am almost there :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this from a batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b *.pdf`) do If %%~zA LSS 3145728 del "%%A"
```

Comment: this is great could you please modify the code to answer my question i am really bad with dos

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, you need to run it from a batch file.

Comment: problem is that it does not like spaces in the filenames it says FILE NOT FOUND

Comment: problem is that it does not like spaces in the filenames it says FILE NOT FOUND

Comment: The trick is to use `delims=;` and `"%%A"`. Tested it and it works fine with spaces now.

Comment: same problem it doesnt like spaces

Comment: @Mrchief let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1675/discussion-between-i-and-mrchief)

Comment: If you want to include subdirectories in the search, `dir /s /b` works with this as well.

Answer (score 2):

BTW: Using PowerShell (on Windows 10) was the easier way for me:

I only did this on the directory where I wish to delete files smaller than 20MB:

```
ls | where {$_.Length -lt 20mb} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: This solution was best for my usecase - can even get an count of what's going to be deleted by using "Measure-Object –Line" instead of "Remove-Item".

I also found "Get-ChildItem [Directory/Path/Here] | Select-Object Extension | Sort-Object Extension | Get-Unique -asString" as a useful command to summarise the objects before they'll be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I used AtomicParsley in a cmd script to add artwork to all my MP4 movies in over 400 sub folders with the --overWrite option. It sometimes barfs and the orignal file is left at less than 2k. I needed a way to find all these messed up MP4 files so I can redownload them.

This is what I used from the command line using Mrchief's example and it works like a charm in windows 7.

```
@for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %A in (`dir /s /b *.mp4`) do @If %~zA LSS 2048 echo "%A"
```

and this is the output after processing 32 of the files

```
    D:\Movie>@for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %A in (`dir /s /b *.mp4`) do @If %~zA LSS 2048 echo "%A"
    "D:\Movie\Action\Deadland (2009)\Deadland (2009).mp4"
    "D:\Movie\Science Fiction\Alien3 (1992)\Alien3 (1992).mp4"

    D:\Movie>
```

you could replace the echo with del and change the 2048 to search for a different size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and its filter capabilities. Here is an excerpt of the `File Selection Options` shown when `robocopy /?` is typed into the command prompt window:

> ```
>              /MAX:n :: MAXimum file size - exclude files bigger than n bytes.
>              /MIN:n :: MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes.
>
>           /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
>           /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
>           /MAXLAD:n :: MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n.
>           /MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.
>                        (If n < 1900 then n = n days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).
> ```

Hence the `/MIN` and `/MAX` options can be applied here. Since we do not want to copy any files, use the `/L` option to list all the items that would be copied without the switch, then parse the returned list by a `for /F` loop, which holds the actual deletion command `del` in the body:

```
set "TARGETDIR=."
set "FILES=*.pdf"
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('
    robocopy "%TARGETDIR%" "%TARGETDIR%" "%FILES%" ^
        /L /IS /FP /NC /NS /NDL /NP /NJH /NJS ^
        /MIN:0 /MAX:3071
') do (
    ECHO del "%%F"
)
```

**After having tested, remove the upper-case `ECHO` from the script to actually delete files.**

Besides `/MIN`, `/MAX` and `/L`, there are several other options defined in the `robocopy` command line, most of which care for the needed output, namely a simple list of full paths of matching files, without any extra information like headers, footers or summaries.

The source and destination directories are both set to our target directory. Normally this would not work, of course (you cannot copy files onto themselves), but since `/L` is stated, the file list is generated, but only if the switch `/IS` is given too (meaning that "same files" are to be regarded).

Answer (score -3):

There isn't a switch in the Del command which will delete files based on filesize.

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure how to do this from DOS, but this is something we have used in the past; it uses VBScript, so you would call this filesoversize.vbs.

```
Dim strPath
Dim lngSize

Dim fso
Dim fold
Dim files
Dim file

lngSize = 10000 ' The threshold in bytes (this is 100k)
strPath = "C:\temp\" 'The folder you want to start in

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fold = fso.GetFolder(strPath)
Set files = fold.files

For Each file In files
    If file.Size <= lngSize Then file.Delete True
Next
```