# smart auto delete batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way to auto delete some backups from a program that are created every hour triggered by a total filesize of all of the backups exceeding 10-14gb
keeping a few patterns as rules for example:

- the very first day
- daily
- the last day
- auto move oldest that is not the first week to a new directory when current rules exceed the max filesize

I need ideas on how to add this to windows 7 preferably with a variable source and alternation directory and a fixed configuration file

- A configurable max file size is a wishful bonus

Comment: I have used the forfiles.exe command for my backups to clear files older than 30 days. `Forfiles.exe -p G:\Backups\GIT_backup -m *.log -d -30 -c "Cmd.exe /C del @path"` That might get you started. As for deleting on size you may need to look at powershell.

Comment: This could be what you need [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764621/delete-files-less-than-a-specific-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764621/delete-files-less-than-a-specific-size) just change it up a little

Comment: You have not asked a question about programming. Instead you are asking someone to write a script for you that will do some of your backup maintenance. This might be better for SuperUser. But your specs are too vague/undefined. Also, batch cannot process numbers larger than 2 gb.

Comment: I was asking for Ideas on how to delete files based on custom rules and create a configuration file it is a program I just stated that the simplest way is the best and a script would be preferable to creating an entire program